# Double join resulting in duplicate records and incorrect row count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know this my mistake with the joins but not sure why I am getting the multiple rows and erroneous row count?

My tsql:

```
DECLARE @PeopleIDTables TABLE ( Column_Name varchar(500) NULL, Table_Name varchar(500) NULL)

INSERT INTO @PeopleIDTables
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME + ',', TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'People_ID'
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME

--SELECT * FROM @PeopleIDTables


SELECT PIT.Table_Name, I.rows NumberRows
FROM @PeopleIDTables PIT
JOIN sys.tables T ON PIT.Table_Name = T.name
JOIN sys.sysindexes I ON T.object_id = I.id
```

Here is an excerpt from my results:

```
PEOPLE  770438
PEOPLE  770438
PEOPLE  770438
PEOPLE  770438
PEOPLE  770438
PEOPLE  770438
PEOPLE  770438
PEOPLE  0
```

When in fact there is only one database on this dev system and it has only one people table. The first half of the query is accurate returning the 64 tables that have a column of People_Id.

Comment: I'm going to guess at least the "PEOPLE" table has multiple indexes on it. And you have a one to many on table to index resulting in more records than  I think you're after. "[Contains one row for each index and table in the current database. XML indexes are not supported in this view. Partitioned tables and indexes are not fully supported in this view; use the sys.indexes catalog view instead.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190283.aspx)"

Comment: Yes Multiple indexes....sorry I didn't think to check that first...DOH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean...

```
SELECT PIT.Table_Name, Max(I.rows) NumberRows
FROM @PeopleIDTables PIT
JOIN sys.tables T ON PIT.Table_Name = T.name
JOIN sys.sysindexes I ON T.object_id = I.id
GROUP BY PIT.Table_Name
```

I assume you want max rows, as an index could be being built or need updating..  and the rowcount here is not always 100% accurate.

Comment: Actually much safer to use sys.partitions than the old backward compatibility sysindexes view, and to use SUM and only on index_id 0 or 1. A partitioned table will have different rows for different partitions, and the MAX() won't be an accurate picture of the number of rows in the table - only the largest partition.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2010/07/15/sql-server-how-to-quickly-retrieve-accurate-row-count-for-table.aspx provides a few methods to accomplish this.  As I wasn't really sure what the end game was, I didn't know if information on the index would be necessary.